# metrics clojure ring middleware not recording metrics

Tags: clojure, compojure, codahale-metrics

In my handler I have the following defined:

```
(def reg (new-registry))

(def app (-> app-routes 
         (expose-metrics-as-json)
         (instrument reg)))
```

If I go to `/metrics` I only see an empty json object.  What am I missing?  Also, the documetation is not clear as to how I can report on the console, it seems `report-to-console` which is in the documentation is not used any more, instead there are reporters but I cannot find any documentation as to how you use reporters.

EDIT:

I have seen that metrics are being added and recorded by looking at this:

```
(meters/rates ((all-metrics reg) "ring.responses.rate.2xx"))
```

And the results are as expected, something like:

```
{1 0.06325196458537237, 5 0.01824839591203641, 15 0.006466051961211013, :total 6}
```

So it seems that although expose-metrics-as-json is creating an endpoint, the metrics are not getting added to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ha! I found that this is actually a bug in the code.  https://github.com/sjl/metrics-clojure/blob/master/metrics-clojure-ring/src/metrics/ring/expose.clj

```
([handler uri registry]
    (expose-metrics-as-json handler uri default-registry {:pretty-print? false}))
```

This ignores the `registry` parameter.  I got things to work by using

```
(expose-metrics-as-json "/metrics" reg {:pretty-print? false})
```

I will fix and create a pull request.

Answer (score 3):

You are not passing the registry to `expose-metrics-as-json`. It falls back to the default registry.

In your threading expression, try changing the second line so that it reads:

```
(def app (-> app-routes
             (expose-metrics-as-json "/metrics" reg)
             (instrument reg)))
```

Comment: I tried this just after I posted the question but it did not work.  I pasted your code in.  The middlewares must be getting picked up because the metrics url is exposed, it just doesn't have any metrics.